# How to convey management that responsibilities given are way off the job description?

Tags: career-development, ethics, resignation

(This is rephrased version of my original question.)

As a person hired for position of senior developer, I was made to work with several groups working on different projects mainly as backup-member in offshore team. Which was okay for some time till I got hang of knowhows. But the routine continues.

The work will definitely keep me busy, but not at all the responsibilities of a senior developer, or no exposure to client/direct billing. So no growth in sight- technical or monetory.

Based on observations, there are very rare chances of getting a position of long-term contribution in any of projects going on. (Considering project strength allocation-other team members-billing-workload etc.)

so **How to convey the management,prudently, that I am utterly disappointed about this** ?

Given the fact that I am still in probation period, how to make best use of my limited liverage ?

Is there any well-known way to make things win-win ?

---

[original]

<del>You crack interestingly tricky interview rounds of a company; for a middle-level (no fresher, no lead) position.
Company offers you almost similar to expected package.
You happily join in and have to serve 6 months of probation period.
Within 3 to 4 months, you realize that in reality of day-to-day work, there is near to no scope for growth on both grounds - Technical Expertise or Seniority Ladder. And the work you dreamed of is nowhere near realization.
What would you do ?
 1. look for new job and resign here, while still in probation period ? (what happens to reputation ?)
 2. wait patiently and gain leverage by good work in daily routine ? (but confirmation only elongates notice-period..)
 3. make use of free time and go for certifications in your field ? (but no real work..)
What could be the risks in a) leaving or b) staying ?</del>

Comment: Why not the obvious "start looking for another job"? No value in resigning now unless your notice period post-probation is *really* onerous.

Comment: This is similar to http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/35813/resign-or-stay-resign-during-probation-or-wait-and-give-3-months-notice/35814#35814, only with dissatisfaction over work instead of dissatisfaction over pay.  The same advice would apply, I think.

Comment: HLGEM's answer on that other question is especially relevant.

Comment: I disagree. The top rated advice on your linked question notes that you can hardly tell other employers you wanted a raise and didn't get one; but this is not at all the same as moving on for lack of career advancement opportunities, which is fairly normal and even acceptable to bring up in interviews. Ambition is fine to admit to, greed is not.

Comment: Also, HLGEM's comment on the other question is entirely salary related. Nothing in this question relates to salary.

Comment: It is easier to get a job when you have a job even one you are still currently in a probation period for.  So if you are unhappy at your current job, you should look for a better opportunity, be prepared that you might burn some bridges by leaving so quickly.  Being in a position for only 6 months really isn't that long.

Comment: I have rephrased the question. Hope it has become more in line with guidelines.

Answer (score 4):

The probation period should be more looked at a try it before you buy it type situation. It is a time period for them to check you out and for you to check them out. If it doesn't fit your goals, then go ahead look around for a new job. Be prepared to answer why you are leaving your current position so soon, but as long as you have a concrete reason it shouldn't hurt. Don't leave until you have something new and don't leave without giving notice. Having gaps in your employment record, without concrete reasons such as attending school full time can hurt your reputation. There is a saying that I hear often "it's easier to find a job when you have a job". People understand changing jobs, they don't understand not working.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a number of years of experience in your previous position, I wouldn't worry too much about quitting after three or four months and explaining to future interviewers that the role didn't offer you the scope for advancement you were looking for. This does weaken your position a little, but as long as you don't appear perpetually dissatisfied it is likely to make only a small difference.

If on the other hand you have been through three or four jobs in the last three years, I would advise you try to stick it out a year or so at least. Hiring managers may see a pattern of frequent job changes as a warning sign.

Do make sure you have a job offer confirmed before handing in your resignation. This is generally good practice unless you are very sure of your position in the market.

Also, make sure you understand how frequently the kind of job you are actually seeking comes on the market, and whether you will be seen as well placed to fill such a role. There is no point in quitting only to have the same problem with your new job.

The value of certifications varies greatly depending on the field and the certification. In some fields - like software development - certification generally has very limited value, in others it is almost essential to be taken seriously.